# RecyclerView - notifyDataSetChanged() - not updating the new list items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am removing and adding same list items as required and updating the view. I know I should use `notifyItemInserted()` during adding new elements. When I have less list items on, it gets updated but when there are more items, no change occurs. Can't understand this. Help would be appreciated!

```
@OnClick(R.id.checkbox_physical_inventory)
    void includeZeroInventoryItems() {
        mItems.clear();
        if (!mZeroInventoryCheckBox.isChecked()) {
             mItems.addAll(queryListItems(false));
        } else {
            mItems.addAll(queryListItems(true));
        }
        setAdapter(mItems);
    }
```

Here's the adapter:

```
private void setAdapter(List<Item> items) {
        if (items != null && mPhysicalInventoryAdapter == null) {
            mPhysicalInventoryAdapter = new PhysicalInventoryAdapter(getContext(), items);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPhysicalInventoryAdapter);
        } else if (mPhysicalInventoryAdapter != null) {
                mPhysicalInventoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you actually updating the items list in the adapter before notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Yes, that code in @OnClick does that.

Comment: i think you should post your `queryListItems` method as well, because I think items in list are added.

Comment: @ShazHemani The `queryListItems` method simply fetches the list from db and does `mItems = queryItems().query()`  . You see that I am clearing the main list everytime before inserting any data right ?  `mItems` is the main list that I am using with the adapter.